# Regex: merge some pattern into one

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a data set with the following content:

```
(event) (tag) [group (artist)] title (form) [addition1] [addition2]
(event) [group (artist)] title (form) [addition1]
[event] [group (artist)] title (form) (addition1)
(tag) [group (artist)] title
[group (artist)] title
title
【tag】 [group (artist)] title 【form】
[group (artist)] title
[group] title
[artist] title
(artist) title
```

I want to get the title from each row.
There are three patterns to match the title:
1.
`([\)\]】]\s*(?P<title>[^\(\)\[\]\【\】\s]*)\s*[\(\[【])`

Which can match some rows like `*] title (*`

2.
`([\)\]】]\s*(?P<title>[^\(\)\[\]\【\】\s]*)` 
match rows like `*] title`

3.
`(?P<title>[^\(\)\[\]\【\】\s]*)`
match rows are just `title`

I have no idea to combine the three rules into one regex.
So, I wrote some Python code to do this:

1. match pattern 1, break, get title
2. not match pattern 1, try match pattern 2
3. loop step 1,2

I'm trying to merge these three rules together into one.

Comment: I think you can use a simple regex like `\([^\)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\]|【[^】]】|(\w*)` that captures title ;).

Comment: @shA.t You are great! I'm should remove other parts, not just get title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
(?:^|[])] +)(?P<title>\w+)(?: +[[【(]|$)
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xF8gU0/2)

**Example**

```
>>> strings = ["(event) (tag) [group (artist)] title (form) [addition1] [addition2]", "(event) [group (artist)] title (form) [addition1]", "[event] [group (artist)] title (form) (addition1)", "(tag) [group (artist)] title", "[group (artist)] title", "title", "【tag 】 [group (artist)] title 【form】", "[group (artist)] title", "[group] title", "[artist] title", "(artist) title"]

>>> for string in strings:
...     re.findall(r'(?:^|[])] +)(?P<title>\w+)(?: +[[【(]|$)', string )                                                             ...
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
['title']
```

Comment: I am not fimiliar with `?:` which seems the key to act magic.And I think I need learn more about `regex Group constructs` . Thanks :)

Comment: `(?:..)` are non capturing groups. which wont' save the matches, but helps to group patterns

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case OP would encounter, but this regex will fail for : `[ (something) something2 (something3) ]` I was thinking of creating a stack like implementation, increment count for any opening brackets, decrements on closing ones. print when count is zero. But if the input is limited to the forms specified, then this solution is the cleanest one...